# not able to fetch "motto in english" text from table in wikipedia.com in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In wikipedia.com website when i search ann university , in right side table i was not able to fetch text "motto in English"
i have a selenium code

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http:\\wikipedia.org");


WebElement lin=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='js-link-box-en']/small"));

lin.click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='searchInput']")).sendKeys("Anna University",Keys.ENTER);

List<WebElement> tablecollection=   driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='infobox vcard']"));

System.out.println(tablecollection.size());
```

last line shows 0 in output

Comment: It returns 2 when i ran

Answer (score 0):

I gave answer to your query

When you print

```
System.out.println(tablecollection.size());
```

it returns 2 , I also ran that script in My Eclipse.

For printing **"Motto in English"** first you have to locate it then using `getText()`
you can print the text

```
driver.get("http://wikipedia.org");
WebElement lin=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='js-link-box-en']/small"));
lin.click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='searchInput']")).sendKeys("Anna University",Keys.ENTER);
List tablecollection= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='infobox vcard']"));
System.out.println(tablecollection.size());
WebElement Motttoele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Motto')]"));
System.out.println(Motttoele.getText());
```